# How to turn off redirect message in curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have a nice bash script which uses curl to log on to a site and initiate an action which all works well.

The output has some noise in it which I would like to remove. The redirect for the authentication page (which works) generates the following message:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/products">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I really just want to turn off the generation of this message but can't see how to.

Comment: Standard output - I'd rather not redirect std output as I want to see genuine errors

Comment: there is no standard output, are you refer to progression meter? `curl -v ...` verbose!

Comment: My bad. Curl is just returning the html, it has nothing to do with the redirect and, as you point out, turning off verbose would stop it appearing. If you post a response then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have figured out your own question, but if not you can do this:

```
curl --silent --fail
```

"--fail or -f" will not show any HTTP output errors on servers and "--silent and -s" should make it completely quiet, however, usually when you get to an "object moved" you can use "-L" for automatic redirection to avoid that output.

I hope this answered your question and for more information: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html or man curl

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said "I'd rather not redirect std output as I want to see genuine errors."  If it was me, I'd capture stdout, check if it was an error response, and if so, display it.

E.g.,

```
rslt=$( curl ... )
stat=${rslt##*\<rsp stat=\"}
stat=${stat%%\"\>*}

if [[ "$stat" == "fail" ]]; then
    # parse: <err code="4" msg="your bad" />
    code=${rslt##*\<err code=\"}
    code=${code%%\"*}
    msg=${rslt##*msg=\"}
    msg=${msg%%\"*}
fi

echo "curl failed: $stat: ($code): $msg"
```

Of course, doing this is very dependent on the format of the HTML response, so it will break if the server changes the response format.